# How can I minus/omit duplicate value from a union of MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Just like the title suggest, I'm having a problem excluding duplicate values from 2 united queries.

My query looks a little complicated so I will try to simplify it by another example:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_hobby uh on uh.user_id = u.id
JOIN teams t on t.id = u.team
JOIN group g on g.id = uh.group and g.name = 'average'
where u.active = 1 and u.team is not null

UNION

SELECT u.name
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_hobby uh on uh.user_id = u.id
JOIN teams t on t.id = u.team
where u.active = 1 and u.team is null
```

so basically, both queries gave me the correct answers but with duplicate values

first query output:
ben, miche, anna, robert

second query output:
jean, charles, anna, robert

How do I use `UNION` in both query where I can omit anna and robert if it already appeared in the first query?

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates by default. But it removes duplicates in `row level`. But you want to remove duplicates in `column level`. Think again: what you want.

Comment: Group is a reserved word in MySQL, and see DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

UNION already removes the duplicate entries.

```
(
SELECT u.name
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_hobby uh on uh.user_id = u.id
JOIN teams t on t.id = u.team
JOIN group g on g.id = uh.group and g.name = 'average'
where u.active = 1 and u.team is not null
)
UNION
(
SELECT u.name
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_hobby uh on uh.user_id = u.id
JOIN teams t on t.id = u.team
where u.active = 1 and u.team is null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Distinct in SELECT ?

Answer (score 0):

Try -  Select distinct x.name from ( query 1 UNION query 2 ) x